# undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am trying to show an item I saved into the database and am getting the error

> undefined local variable or method

Here is my controller:

```
class YogasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

  def index
   @yoga = Yoga.all
  end

  def create
   @yoga = Yoga.new(yoga_params)
    if @yoga.save
      redirect_to yogas_path 
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
  end

def update
 @yoga = Yoga.find(params[:id])
 @yoga = Yoga.update(yoga_params)
 redirect_to root_path 
end

def new
 @yoga = Yoga.new
end

def show
 @yoga = Yoga.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
 @yoga = Yoga.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
 @yoga = Yoga.find(params[:id])
 @yoga.destroy
 redirect_to root_path
end 


private 
 def yoga_params
 params.require(:yoga).permit(:post, :title)
end  
end
```

Here is the show.html.erb:

```
<%= yoga.title %>
<%= yoga.post %>
```

Here are the routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :yogas
 devise_for :users
 get 'show' => 'yogs#show'
 root 'yogas#index'
 end
```

Here is what I have in the schema.rb:

```
  create_table "yogas", force: true do |t|
     t.string   "title"
     t.string   "post"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
   end
```

It is saving to the DB and redirecting to the root path after it is made and thats about it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On what line do you get this error?

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `yoga' /show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> undefined local variable or method `yoga'

The error is because you are using `yoga` instead of `@yoga`.Your code in the `show.html.erb` should look like this

```
<%= @yoga.title %>
<%= @yoga.post %>
```

as you have `@yoga` instance variable defined in the `show method` of your controller.

And also,as pointed out by **@Iceman**,this line `@yoga = Yoga.update(yoga_params)`in your `update` method should look like this `@yoga = @yoga.update(yoga_params)`,and this line  `get 'show' => 'yogs#show'` in your `routes` should be  `get 'show' => 'yogas#show'`

Comment: `@yoga = Yoga.update(yoga_params)` should also be `@yoga = @yoga.update(yoga_params)`. routes.rb looks a little strange too, `get 'show' => 'yogs#show'`

Comment: Damn-it.. I am very thankful for this answer, It drives me nuts when is is something that simple.. Thank you for taking the time!